# Why is the dot product of a vector equivalent to the matrix multiplication of its components?

Tags: vectors

The geometric definition of the dot product ($ab \cos \theta$) is very easy to understand.

To some extent, I can understand why matrix multiplication works (if either vector $a$ or $b$ is parallel to the $x$ or $y$-axis) because it ultimately simplifies to the geometric definition.

However, I can't get an intuitive feel as to why it works for any two arbitrary vectors.

Can someone give an intuitive feel of why?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227131/221811